# JSF 2.0 Using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, xhtml, jsf, facelets

I am using JSF 2.0 with eclipse 3.4 and Tomcat6. For Facelets I need to create XHTML files.
Now the problem is that there is no XHTML file in eclipse.
I can make it using a new and convert its etension XHTML
but i am coding it is not showing any tags in autocomplete. In JSP file when I write `<h:` it shows all relevant tags of and same for `<f:` but not in XHTML file.
Which one I make using new file in Eclipse please tell me how it show also all tags 
which relevant to `<h:` and any other.

Comment: You need the JEE edition of Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need [Eclipse for **Java EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) (note the **EE**). It not only includes WTP with JSF tooling, but also much more, like a builtin database manager, JPA assist, etc.
2. As Facelets is relatively new, there's no builtin support for this yet. To get autocompletion to work for Facelets files anyway, go to *Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP* and then add `*.xhtml` as file association and set default encoding to `UTF-8`.

   **Update**: Since Eclipse 3.6 there's builtin support for Facelets files. Further, the Glassfish server plugin and the Jboss Tools plugin also ships with more advanced Facelets support. The Jboss Tools plugin even comes with EL autocompletion and linking with right managed bean classes.

Comment: Thanks sir.Please if it possible please write a tutorial for JSF2.0.As ou write you for JSF1.2.

Answer (score 0):

create new > others> web> html> click next
enter file name with extension .xhtml >finish

Comment: Or just upgrade Eclipse to at least 3.6, which offers builtin support for Facelets files.